# Why are my new roof shingles showing these lighter patches in cool weather?

Tags: roof

[image: roof pic]
New roof shows patches of lighter shingles. Is it heat loss? Installation error?

Comment: Changes in insulation beneath...

Comment: Without knowing what your "cool weather" consists of, it looks like frost patches.

Comment: It was about 35 degrees out this morning. The frost patches were not there previous to the new roof and they only cover those 10 areas. Not on any neighbors' homes either. -thank you

Answer (score 1):

The roof area that has the lighter color is insulated closer to the roof than the other areas. Insulation is keeping the frost from melting in the lighter areas. The stripes you see between the patches are the location of the rafters, which do not insulate as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Uneven drying

Once we got a large batch of stone, and I asked the contractor "why'd you get two colors?"  He looked at the angry clouds and told me he would take care of it right away.  Sure enough, five minutes into the rainstorm, he had already swiched the light ones out to the darker gray.   I told him I liked the lighter gray and he said "check back in a day".  *The guy is a miracle worker.   I'll ask if he does roofs.*

Seriously, you're looking at an area of the roof that is dryer than the rest.   Or it may have a crust of frost moreso than the rest of the roof.

Parts of the roof dry/melt at different rates because of differences in what's under the roof.  While this can be a "canary in a coal mine" warning of a problem, it may also just be normal.  Canaries in coal mines also die for other reasons.